# Change ColumnSpan from TextBlock on ListView

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm building a UWP app and I have a problem with my ListView. I want to change the ColumnSpan from the TextBlock inside my ListView.

```
                    <ListView Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="#0062AD" BorderThickness="1" ItemsSource="{Binding BusRoutes}" x:Name="Routes1" SelectionMode="None"   IsItemClickEnabled="False"  Padding="0 10 0 0">

                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Width="400">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="startingPoint" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"  Padding="0 10 0 10" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding hours}"/>
                                <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center"  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Padding="0 10 0 10" x:Name="endingPoint" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding hours2}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

What I mean is that I want to set to the TextBlox with name startingPoint ColumnSpan = 2 and make the TextBlock with name endingPoint Collapsed programmatically. Is this possible?

Comment: I didn't understand best but you can try `YourGrid.setColumnSpan(textblock,2);`

Comment: You want that when textblock endingPoint is visible, width of starting point should be half. and when endingpoint is collapsed width of startingpoint should be full i.e. it should display in whole area where both textboxes were showing. Is this you want to ask. or anything else?

Comment: I want to set programmatically columnspan to the startingPoint and make endingPoint unvisible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can change the column span and set the visibility programmatically by using :

```
endingPoint.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; //to make it invisible
Grid.SetColumnSpan(startingPoint, 2); //to change it the 2 column span
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you facing issue with finding the controls instead list view. Since you have done the binding. Best way is create view model properties for visiblity and columnspan and set if programmatically. Bind the properties to your xaml. Since you already have bindings its should be easy to do